# Error while extending AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am now trying an android location app, but in this source code, i found that i cannot extends AsyncTask although i import the library.

This code is found from others comment, which i have tried and showed errors.

> Error:(90, 5) error: LocServ.SendToServer is not abstract and does not override abstract method doInBackground(String...) in AsyncTask

---

```
package com.example.user.locserv;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class LocServ extends Service implements LocationListener {
    private static String url_insert_location = "http://172.20.10.4/testing/insert.php";
    public static String LOG = "Log";

    JSONObject jsonParser = new JSONObject();

    private Context mContext;

    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    boolean canGetLocation = false;
    Location location;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0;

    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000;

    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public LocServ(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public LocServ() {
        super();
        mContext = LocServ.this;
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i(LOG, "Service started");
        Log.i("asd", "This is sparta");

        new SendToServer().execute(Double.toString(getLocation().getLongitude()), Double.toString(getLocation().getLatitude()));
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(LOG, "Service created");

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy(); {
            Log.i(LOG, "Service destroyed");
        }
    }

    class SendToServer extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackGround(String... la) {
            try {
                Log.i("string", la[0]);
                String longi = la[0];
                String lati = la[1];

                Log.d("value", lati);
                Log.d("value", longi);
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", longi));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", lati));

                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_insert_location, "POST", params);
                Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("error", e.toString());
            }
            return "call";
        }

    }

    public Location getLocation(){
        try{
            locationManager= (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            isGPSEnabled=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            isNetworkEnabled=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if(!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled){

            }
            else{
                this.canGetLocation=true;
                    if(isNetworkEnabled){

                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                                this);
                        Log.d("Network","Network");
                        if(locationManager != null){
                            location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                            if(location != null){
                                latitude=location.getLatitude();
                                longitude=location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                if(isGPSEnabled){
                    if(location==null){
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled","GPS Enalbled");
                        if(locationManager!=null){
                            location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if(location!=null){
                                latitude=location.getLatitude();
                                longitude=location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return location;

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        new SendToServer().execute(Double.toString(getLocation().getLongitude()),Double.toString(getLocation().getLatitude()));

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you using this code, Please add full code.~

Comment: Here's the code

Comment: What is the error while extending the Asynctask ?

Comment: Error:(90, 5) error: LocServ.SendToServer is not abstract and does not override abstract method doInBackground(String...) in AsyncTask

Comment: @Jain The answer is perfect below, replace your `doInBackGround` to `doInBackground`.

Comment: @Jian If you move your mouse on that line, a red light bulb will appear and you can autocomplete the correct method definition(s)

Comment: Also, Apache HTTP is deprecated. You can use different HTTP libraries, and you wouldn't even need an Asynctask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relpace this:

```
doInBackGround     // [g] does not start with capital letter
```

With this:

```
doInBackground
```

Comment: Thanks, I found that

Comment: I can extend it, but there is one more error, which located at the  JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_insert_location, "POST", params);

Comment: and it shows this error message, 
Error:(104, 45) error: cannot find symbol method makeHttpRequest(String,String,ArrayList<NameValuePair>)

Comment: @W4R10CK Thanks :D
@JianWeiLong class [JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) does not have a method named `makeHttpRequest`, you must be doing something wrong!

Comment: That method is not called on an JSONObject... If this answer is the only problem, question should be closed as typo, and leave this as a comment

Comment: Thanks for you guys help.